# Caffe - How to change the dtype of caffe weights using pycaffe?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network, pycaffe

I have a pre-trained faster-rcnn caffemodel. I'm able to get the weights of the model using `net.params[pr][0].data`. As of now the weights are of numpy float32 type. I would like to reduce it to float 16 just to reduce the size of the model.

Comment: were you successful?

Comment: It was not supported in Caffe when I tried in Nov 2016, don't know whether they support now. I ended up doing it in C. However tensorflow supports float precision conversion after training.

Answer (score 1):

To change the type of the weights in order to save memory for the storage, you can use NumPy's [astype](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html)(float16), for example

```
net.params[pr][0].data = net.params[pr][0].data.astype(numpy.float16)
```

However Caffe won't support it at inference / training time so you'll need to reconvert it to float32. 
However there are some caffe repositories that support float16, such as [Ristretto](https://github.com/pmgysel/caffe), or [NVCaffe](https://github.com/NVIDIA/caffe) for NVidia / Intel's [clCaffe](https://github.com/01org/caffe) for OpenCL on Intel GPUs.